# Can we combine policy evaluation and value iteration steps for solving model-based MDP?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, value-iteration, policy-iteration

In Sutton & Barto (2nd edition), at the very end on page 83, the following is mentioned:

> In general, the entire class of truncated policy iteration algorithms can be thought of as sequences of sweeps, some of which use policy evaluation updates and some of which use value iteration updates.

and this on the beginning of page 84:

> max operation is added to some sweeps of policy evaluation.

I understand that the entire class of truncated policy iteration algorithms can be classified as generalized policy iteration (GPI). Also, I know value iteration (VI) is a combination of one sweep of policy evaluation (PE) and one sweep of policy improvement.

**My question**: What do we mean by combining multiple PE and VI updates in truncated policy iteration?